# Converting string to integer in Logic-App Liquid Map

Tags: json, type-conversion, liquid, azure-logic-apps

Im trying to convert a string to an integer inside Logic-App Liquid maps.
My Liquid is like this

```
{% assign var = "2" %}
{% assign number = var| Plus: 1 %}

{
"number":"{{number}}"
}
```

And the output (below) is calculated as 21 (string concatination) and not 3 as expected.

```
{
    "number": "21"
}
```

Any suggestion on how to change this string to an Integer so I can do mathematical calculations on it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to some test, it seems `{% assign number = var | Plus: 1 %}` can't convert the string to integer when we run it in logic app liquid (although it works in liquid outside  logic app, as many websites and posts mentioned on internet).

But we can do it by below liquid template in logic app:

```
{% assign var = "2" %}
{% assign var1 = var | Round %}
{% assign number = var1 | Plus: 1 %}

{
    "var1":{{var1}},
    "number":{{number}}
}
```

It works fine in my logic app and below is the screenshot of the result:
[image]